# Scope issues with multiple instances of Angular Directives with isolate scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, isolate-scope

I was trying to create a table directive which lets create tables with add, delete and edit options.

HTML

```
// User table
<atable config="userTable"></atable>
// Age table
<atable config="ageTable"></atable>
```

JS (Controller)

```
var userData = [{
    un: 'user1',
    pwd: 'password',
    ph: '500000000',
    id: 2
},..];

$scope.userTable = {
    cols: ['Username', 'Password', 'Contact'],
    rows: userData,
    deleteRow: true,
    deleteHandler: function (id) {
        console.log(id);
        for (var i = 0; i < userData.length; i++) {
            if (userData[i].id == id) {
                userData.splice(i, 1);
                break;
            }
        }
    },..
};
```

Similarly I have created ageData and ageTable config for the second table.

JS (Directive)

```
.directive("atable", function () {
return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
        config: '='
    },
    template: 'Look at fiddle'
    controller: function ($scope) {
        $scope.deleteRow = function (row) {
            $scope.config.currEditRow = angular.copy(row);
        }
        ...
    }
}
})
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vikasediga/f0kq7c8g/2/).

Delete row works for the first table but not for the second instance. I figured that the deleteHandler of the userTable is being called when trying to delete something in the ageTable. I can guess that this is scoping issue but can't figure this out.

Comment: What version of angular are you using? That fiddle is using 1.01 which is ancient. There is a reason they wouldn't let you put a link in to fiddle and no code. questions should be self contained

Comment: Please add *relevant* parts of the code (please don't just copy-paste everything) in the question itself - don't rely on external links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that your template includes the modal definition, and the same ID is used for both. So the delete button in the second table is actually showing the delete dialog (with ID 'delPane') for the first table.

Take a look at a service for displaying the modal from javascript, such as https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ (see section on Modals).